# Add images to image slider while running, with jQuery and Flask

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, flask, sijax

I need my jQuery image slider (I don't have one yet) to update after a few seconds to see if there are new images. It has to do this without refreshing the page (asynchronously)

To do this, there needs to be a javascript function that sends a request to Flask (via Sijax) to search for new images. Via Sijax, Flask returns the source of the images to the page, so jQuery can update the image slider and add the new images, without refreshing the page.

(How) is this possible? Is there a jQuery image slider that can do this for me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

jquery can work asynchronous with [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'yourpage',
        success: function(result) {
         //Do your thing
        }
});
```

Now it is up to you the way it will work

Comment: I think I already have something like that, but I need an image slider that can accept new images while it's playing its slideshow, without refreshing.

For example, it could look each 20 seconds in a div and add new images that are inside it. To get these images, my Flask app uses jquery to put <img src="..." /> inside the div (using append)

Comment: I'm using Galleria as an image slider, but I don't know if it can help me

I start the stream to get my images by using `Sijax.request('startstream');` which is executed when the document is ready. The startstream function in my python file executes this in the end:

`obj_response.script("""
       Galleria.run('#galleria', {

           extend: function(options) {

               this.push({ image: '%s' });
           }
       });""" % str(image[0]) )` . str(image[0]) is an img tag (`<img src="..." />`)